# Moto 360 custom watch face lag

Tags: lag, watch, wear-os, motorola

I'm developing watch faces for android wear devices. Everything was working well but we encountered problems on Moto 360. My users complain that quite big lag occures when user wants to activate the watch. Screen is shown after from 1 to 5 sec after touching the screen (sometimes it works faster, sometimes slower). Anyone had problem like that? My apps are tested on Samsung Gear Live and LG G Watch and works fine on them. I'm not able to get Moto right now.

You can check apps that I made here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Zuhanden

This is my manifest (maybe something is missing?):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.smartwatchface.watch.face.speedometer.android.wear"
    android:versionCode="14"
    android:versionName="1.9" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="20"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:name="de.zuhanden.smartwatch.wear.squares.WatchApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="de.zuhanden.smartwatch.wear.squares.ui.activities.RectWatchfaceActivity"
            android:allowEmbedded="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/watchface_label_rect"
            android:taskAffinity="" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview"
                android:resource="@drawable/watchface_launcher_rect" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="de.zuhanden.smartwatch.wear.squares.ui.activities.RoundWatchfaceActivity"
            android:allowEmbedded="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/watchface_label_round"
            android:taskAffinity="" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview"
                android:resource="@drawable/watchface_launcher_round" />
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="de.zuhanden.smartwatch.wear.squares.ui.activities.SpeedometerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="de.zuhanden.smartwatch.wear.squares.services.DataLayerListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Google play services are used in application, not in watchface, so it should not be a problem. I also use this method to check watch state and control animation fps:

```
@Override
public void onDisplayChanged(int displayId) {
    final Display display = displayManager.getDisplay(displayId);

    if (display != null) {
        switch(display.getState()) {

        case Display.STATE_DOZING:
            onScreenDim();
            break;

        case Display.STATE_OFF:
            onScreenOff();
            break;

        default:
            //  Not really sure what to so about Display.STATE_UNKNOWN, so
            //  we'll treat it as if the screen is normal.
            onScreenAwake();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When onScreenAwake() is called i switch to high fps (i call invalidate() repeatedly inside Handler) and inside onScreenOff() i stop handler and start refreshing screen only once per minute.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I have both an LG and Moto 360 - and something is really lagging the Moto 360 - even with frequent reboots. I have a count down timer with 1000ms delay on handler - and just change a button - and it can't even count down consistent ;)  I'm not sure what it is.  As the game Flopsy Droid seems to perform fine compared to the LG.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. reference this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808229/fragment-in-round-wear-watch-turning-black-in-emulator-watch - it seems that the Round activity may be inflated twice - and I literally was getting overdraw of two entire screens.  THIS MAY not be your problem - but I still suggest you put some logs in all your onCreate places and really be sure you aren't getting duplicate calls that happen only when the Round exists.