# Fragment in round Wear watch turning black in emulator/watch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, wear-os

Im getting a black screen on my Android Wear round watch (on square it works).
Both layouts show up OK in the Android Studio layout design.

Project to test:

https://bitbucket.org/powder366/motoblack

Im using the following code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
...
```

Layout my_fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".WearFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Hi1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/UnitsStyle"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:text="Hi2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/BaseStyle"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:text="Hi3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/UnitsStyle"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Calling it from:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter
...
    public MenuAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, Handler handler) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
    mHandler = handler;
    myFragment = new MyFragment();
}
...
@Override
public Fragment getFragment(int rowNum, int colNum) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("getFragment(%d, %d)", rowNum, colNum));

    if(colNum == 0) {
        return myFragment;
    }

    if(colNum == 1) {
        final SecondFragment switchAction = SecondFragment.newInstance(mHandler);
        return switchAction;
    }

    return null;
}
...
```

Which is called from:

```
public class WearActivity extends Activity {
...

private GridViewPager gridViewPager;
private MenuAdapter menuAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Create(Wear)");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wear_activity);

    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(WearActivity.this, getFragmentManager(), mHandler);
            gridViewPager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            gridViewPager.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
        }
    });
}
...
```

Have anyone seen this or can give me a hint on how to solve it?

Update:

wear_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity"
  app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity"
  tools:context=".WearActivity"
  tools:deviceIds="wear">
</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

rect_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  tools:deviceIds="wear_square">

<com.xyz.my.ScrollableGridViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

round_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  tools:deviceIds="wear_round">

<com.xyz.my.ScrollableGridViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Extra info:

```
public class ScrollableGridViewPager extends GridViewPager {
...
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the `MyFragment` fragment in `gridViewPager` is displayed but its black? Maybe it is just not displayed? Please post your `wear_activity.xml` and both layouts for `rect` and `round` screens.

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga I have updated with code and link to bitbucket to test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not so trivial, so I hope that I've described it pretty clearly.

### Reason #1:

The real reason of this issue is that the `onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub)` method is **called twice** on the round device.

It is invoked for the first time when the `rect_activity.xml` is inflated:

```
WearActivity$1.onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub) line: 26 
WatchViewStub.inflate() line: 133   
WatchViewStub.onMeasure(int, int) line: 141 
WatchViewStub(View).measure(int, int) line: 16648
```

But right after that the second call to this method is done with newly inflated `round_activity.xml` when `onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets)` is dispatched:

```
WearActivity$1.onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub) line: 26 
WatchViewStub.inflate() line: 133   
WatchViewStub.onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets) line: 112   
WatchViewStub(View).dispatchApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets) line: 6051  
WatchViewStub(ViewGroup).dispatchApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets) line: 5435 
SwipeDismissLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets) line: 5439    
PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).dispatchApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets) line: 5439 
ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(View) line: 1170
```

I don't know whether this issue occurs only on emulator or on real device also, but I think this should be reported as a bug in wearable-support-lib (in `WatchViewStub` component to be precise). Such behavior is not documented anywhere.

### Reason #2 (visual consequences of #1):

The issue above sounds like it should do pretty nothing... New layout is inflated (so the old one is removed), new `MenuAdapter` will be created (the old one will not be used any more so who cares), and this newly created `MenuAdapter` should be set as an adapter in new `GridViewPager`. Everything should "reset" so it should still works fine (apart that the performance issue due to the fact that layout is inflated two times instead of just once).

Not exactly... because here is the tricky part with `GridViewPager`.

I don't know the exact source codes of `GridViewPager` and `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` but it seems to be similar to `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` code. `FragmentPagerAdapter` adds newly created fragment to the `FragmentManager` with special `tag` that is composed with `id` of the `ViewPager` and position of given child fragment:

```
122    private static String More ...makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
123        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
124    }
```

Once a fragment is added to the `FragmentManager` (in current `Activity`) it can be referenced by this `tag` name in future.
The real problem is caused by the fact that `onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub)` method is called twice. The first fragment is created in first `MenuAdapter` and added to the container with id `R.id.pager` (from the `rect_activity.xml`). Then `round_activity.xml` is inflated and second call to `onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub)` is invoked - new fragment is created in new `MenuAdapter` and added to newly inflated `GridViewPager` with the same id: `R.id.pager`. So the first fragment and second one want to have exactly the same `tag` in `FragmentManager`.

In standard `FragmentPagerAdapter` if fragment with given `tag` is already present in `FragmentManager` it is attached to it's previous parent again. You can see source codes here:

```
50     @Override
51     public Object More ...instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
52         if (mCurTransaction == null) {
53             mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
54         }
55 
56         // Do we already have this fragment?
57         String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position);
58         Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
59         if (fragment != null) {
60             if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + position + ": f=" + fragment);
61             mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
62         } else {
63             fragment = getItem(position);
64             if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + position + ": f=" + fragment);
65             mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
66                     makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position));
67         }
68         if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
69             fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
70         }
71 
72         return fragment;
73     }
```

So probably the situation is similar and the first fragment is reused, which was added to the first `GridViewPager` with id `R.id.pager` - but this parent is not there any more so the fragment cannot be attached anywhere (and be displayed). This is the implementation thing that there can be only one `ViewPager`-like parent with given id in one `Activity`.

For one more experiment I've set different ids for both `GridViewPagers`. One with `rect_activity.xml` has id `R.id.pager1` and another one in `round_activity.xml` has `R.id.pager2'.

```
final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(WearActivity.this, getFragmentManager());
            GridViewPager gridViewPager1 = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
            if(gridViewPager1!=null) {          // rect_activity
                gridViewPager1.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
            }

            GridViewPager gridViewPager2 = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager2);
            if(gridViewPager2!=null) {          // round_activity
                gridViewPager2.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
            }
        }
    });
```

In first pass only `gridViewPager1` is found and only its adapter is set. Similar in the second pass - only adapter for `gridViewPager2` is set.
Because `GridViewPagers` have different ids there is no collision in fragment `tags`, so the end result is as expected.
But this is only to prove the theory described above:)

[image]

### Solution:

`WatchViewStub` is used to provide different layouts for `rect` and `round` screens. I can see that you use exactly the same layouts for both shapes. You can get rid of the `WatchViewStub` and just do like this:

```
public class WearActivity extends Activity {

    private GridViewPager gridViewPager;
    private MenuAdapter menuAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rect_activity);

        menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(WearActivity.this, getFragmentManager());
        gridViewPager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        gridViewPager.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
    }
}
```

this will make your example work perfectly without the use of `WatchViewStub`.

Comment: Many thanks! It works. Wish I had powers like you:-)

Comment: What an in depth answer. Thank you so much. At least this problem will only cost me one work day of frustration.

Comment: WOW, Thank you, I've spent a few hours on trying to figure out why I could not find my views, I would have stared at this for a few more hours... that is a very stupid implementation of a component that suppose to distinct between two types of devices... there is no point in inflating both layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using a normal ViewPager. Maciej Ciemięga's experimental fix using separate id's for the different layouts worked for me. I posted a bug report to Google with links to this question and answer. I would've commented on the answer but I don't have enough reputation yet to leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So Android lifecycle has gone down the drain, completely... as of now onCreate doesn't really create anything... it has to wait until the **WatchViewStub.onMeasure(...)**  would be called (Which is called long after the onResume is done) and only then it inflates the proper view(or first the rectangle view and then the circle view, that is the reason for the double call)... which can cause a ton of issues.

I really like consistency(not really sure why) so I've tried to make sure that the onViewInflated would be only processed once for both rectangle and round devices, regardless how many times it is called and here is my solution:

```
class MyActivity
        extends Activity {


    private class WearableUI_Helper
            implements OnLayoutInflatedListener {


        public Runnable processView = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                processView(stub);
                postRender();
            }
        };

        private WatchViewStub stub;

        private Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        public void postRender() {
            if (stub != null)
                render();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            Log.w("Step", "onLayoutInflated");
            this.stub = stub;
            h.removeCallbacks(processView);
            h.postAtFrontOfQueue(processView);
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        Log.w("Step", "Render");
        // do here all the rendering you need... set images and text and all
        // and never call this method directly because it is only initialized
        // long after the onResume is called.
    }

    WearableUI_Helper uiHelper = new WearableUI_Helper();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.w("Step", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.layout__app_notification_action);
        WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(uiHelper);
    }

    private void processView(WatchViewStub stub) {
        Log.w("Step", "processView");
        // here you should find all you views and assign them to your activity fields.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.postRender(); // if you call render() here it will crash!!
    }
}
```

I've tested this with both round and rectangle Emulators, and got the desired results.
I didn't try this in Fragments and I don't see a reason this should fail there.

I hope I've saved you some frustration...